# Can’t Boot into Windows

Tags: windows, upgrade

I just installed my new 970 Pro and I was using the Samsung Migration software. It failed at 100% then restarted but I got a 0xc0000098 error. I’ve tried a number of things but I end up getting a 0xc000000d error code. I made a system image but I used easeus to change my boot drive to GPT AFTER I made my image (FML I am dumb) and now I can’t restore from that image. 
I don’t know what to do at this point. I still have my system image so I have my data but I’m worried that if I just try to format my HDD and make it MBR again that it won’t work. 
Help plz LTT fam.
Also, any ideas on migration after I get this resolved would be great. I have a full copy of easeus master 11 but it didn’t work the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

**a system image usually can be mounted from linux.**
if you are interested in accessing the backup, provide more information about the files.

i recommend [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io) and install Xubuntu to any USB flash drive. Boot the live distro from USB flash drive. Find the *.vhdx file from File Manager. open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T. Check if you can mount the backup. If there are more than one partition (check with `lsblk /dev/nbd0`) create more mount points (`mkdir`) and mount all partitions. Copy all files from all partitions to new partition (replace the ... with destination drive)

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install qemu-utils
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd --read-only --connect=/dev/nbd0 --format=vhdx /media/xubuntu/.../*.vhdx
lsblk /dev/nbd0
```

repeat this, change the mount point (/media/xubuntu/**windows**) for each partition

```
mkdir /media/xubuntu/windows
mount /dev/nbd0p1 -t ntfs-3g -r /media/xubuntu/windows
cd /media/xubuntu/windows
ls -an
rsync -avxHAWX --numeric-ids ./ /media/xubuntu/...
```

Make sure the destination partition is set as active. run gparted and set the boot flag.

Still in Linux, find the path of bootloader directory with
`find /media/xubuntu/... -iname bcdboot.exe`
and make a note of the path, for example
/media/xubuntu/.../**efi/microsoft/boot**/bcdboot.exe

**once you have copied the backup to new partition, you have to restore the bootloader**

Reboot from your Windows DVD. Make sure you boot the UEFI part of the disk.
Press Shift+F10 (or Fn+Shift+F10) to open the command prompt.
enter the bootloader directory `C:\efi\microsoft\boot` (see above)
Recreate the boot sector:

```
cd c:\efi\microsoft\boot
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bcdboot.exe C:\Windows
bootrec.exe /scanos
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Now stop the DVD Setup and reboot Computer. If Windows still not booting from GPT Partition, you may have separate partitions for boot and system. If your new partition is empty, you can use `dd` instead of rsync. start from Xubuntu and repeat from beginning to qemu-nbd. do not mount the partitions, instead write the whole disk. **Warning: replace /dev/sda with your right ssd location!**

```
dd if=/dev/nbd0 of=/dev/sda bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

Comment: What I would like to really do is just fix the errors I am getting with my current drive or change the drive back to MBR so that I can just restore using my system image

Comment: depending on what kind of system image it might restore MBR

Comment: It won’t let me restore since my image was made when it was MBR and then like an idiot I changed my drive to GPT without backing it up. So now my drive is GPT and I can’t restore from my MBR image

Comment: thats why information about what kind of backup program used is required. i recommend to use a live distro of any linux and run gparted and gdisk

Comment: I just used windows system image. And I was trying to restore using a windows recovery usb using restore from system image